# SSIS ADO.net using transaction Failure

Tags: ssis, transactions, bulkinsert

I am trying to implement start ,commit and rollback transaction with my ado.net destination. The problem is when i am checking the bulk insert property as true the insertion is getting failed. Whereas the transaction works fine if the bulk insert property is disabled. But we require bulk insert any idea on this.

1. Ado.net as destination
2. Start Transaction
3. Commit
4. Rollback
5. Using Sql client data provider

   Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Unexpected existing transaction.